Add shape In VBA for Word, defining size, position on page, and color
I am entirely new to VBA and am trying to learn from already posted examples but need a little boost from experts.
I am trying to create Word template that displays a grey sidebar with text for instructions on each page. When users create a new page, I would like to provide them with a macro that easily places the same sidebar on the new page.
This is what I could find so far:
Sub Sidebar() 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Shp As Shape, Rng As Range, Hght As Single, Wdth As Single
Hght = InchesToPoints(11): Wdth = InchesToPoints(2.17)
With ActiveDocument
    Set Shp = .Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=RelativeVerticalPosition = 0, _
    Top:=RelativeHorizontalPosition = 0 - Hght, _
    Width:=Wdth, Height:=Hght)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`

It beautifully places the sidebar in the correct place with the correct dimensions. However, it is, in accordance with my theme colors, green. How do I alter the code to change he fill and outline color?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. For simple things like adding shapes in Word or Excel and fill colours you can often get away with recording a macro whilst you do whatever you want to do/automate. Then you will get the approximate syntax and which of the various twisty little passages all alike you have to alter to get the right effect. Inspecting the object in the debugger can also be very informative. The code will need a lot of tidying up but it should help you get started.

Thank you for your feedback, @MartinBrown. I am trying to record the macro, but no matter which way I try, it does not record. For example, I recorded adding a shape only, but the code that was returned looks like this: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
End Sub           Could it be that I am not allowed to record macros?

This would be too long for a comment and also illegible so constitutes a partial answer to the original question with a selection of the right structures initialised (recorded as Macro1). A breakpoint in the code should allow you to scout around for any other settings that you want to change.
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro 
'  
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 646.5, 149.25, 178.5, 88.5).Select
  With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
     .Visible = msoTrue
     .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) '' pale grey .RGB(192,192,192)
     .Transparency = 0
     .Solid
  End With
  With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    .Transparency = 0
  End With
  Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 18
  Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 10.5
  Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 25.3589833333
End Sub

The above is a direct recorded macro on Excel from Office 16. I wonder why you can't do that on your system. I had a quick scout around in settings but couldn't see anything obvious that would hobble macro recording.
